# Hide form depending on the status of the selected data from database

Tags: php

I have a php page which contains a table. Users can filter it to view the unreplied, replied, or combined (both unreplied and replied).

The table rows are clickable and goes to another page called `view_details.php`
wherein data are displayed according to the selected table row id

```
$(".btnView").click(function(){
   if(ID!=""){
        window.location = 'admin.php?action=view&id=' + ID;

    }else{
        // alert that no table row is selected
    }
});
```

I want to know how to make a condition where:

1. (a) The form inside view_details.php will be hidden if the selected table row is replied already and (b) show the replied message instead
2. The form will be shown if it is unreplied

This is what's inside `view_details.php`

```
<?php
    if( isset($ViewMessage) && count($ViewMessage)>0 ){
        foreach($ViewMessageas $ViewMessage){
            echo '
                <p><b>Title: </b>'.$ViewMessage['title'].'</p>
                <p><b>To: </b>'.$ViewMessage['recepient'].'</p>
                <p><b>Message: </b>'.$ViewMessage['message_body'].'</p>

                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label>Reply:</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="response_msg"> </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="concern_msg" value="'.$ViewConcern['concern_msg'].'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Send</button>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="admin.php?action=concerns">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
                ';
        }
    }else{
        echo '
                <h3>No records found</h3>
                </tr>
                ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: 1. Please show your `<table>` code, and the *relevant* PHP code as well. 2. Why are you using Javascript to redirect user to a different page? Use `<a href="...">...</a>` instead. 3. What is `$ViewMessage` and from where you're getting this?

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul 2. I use javascript because I have to check whether a table row is selected before clicking the view button 3. I am using MVC

Comment: check to see if `row == x` - use a ternary operator; seems to be what the question is about.